# Grouping XML records with field name atttribute with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to select the values from this XML and produce grouped XML output. 
This is the XML file: I'm trying to grab the individual field values by using the name attribute: select="field[@name='EmployeeEmployeeID']"
** ***Edited to add Score field*** **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <record>
    <field name="EmployeeEmployeeID">1234</field>
    <field name="EmployeeFirstName">John</field>
    <field name="EmployeeInitial">A</field>
    <field name="EmployeeLastName">Doe</field>
    <field name="EmployeeTitle">Title</field>
    <field name="ReviewRequest">2017 Review</field>
    <field name="Goal">Goal Title1A</field>
    <field name="Score">3</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="EmployeeEmployeeID">1234</field>
    <field name="EmployeeFirstName">John</field>
    <field name="EmployeeInitial">A</field>
    <field name="EmployeeLastName">Doe</field>
    <field name="EmployeeTitle">Title</field>
    <field name="ReviewRequest">2017 Review</field>
    <field name="Goal">Goal Title2A</field>
    <field name="Score">2</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="EmployeeEmployeeID">1234</field>
    <field name="EmployeeFirstName">John</field>
    <field name="EmployeeInitial">A</field>
    <field name="EmployeeLastName">Doe</field>
    <field name="EmployeeTitle">Title</field>
    <field name="ReviewRequest">2018 Review</field>
    <field name="Goal">Goal Title1B</field>
    <field name="Score">2</field>
  </record>
  <record>
    <field name="EmployeeEmployeeID">1234</field>
    <field name="EmployeeFirstName">John</field>
    <field name="EmployeeInitial">A</field>
    <field name="EmployeeLastName">Doe</field>
    <field name="EmployeeTitle">Title</field>
    <field name="ReviewRequest">2018 Review</field>
    <field name="Goal">Goal Title2B</field>
    <field name="Score">3</field>
  </record>
</ExportXML>
```

I am trying to get this output:
** ***Edited to add Score field and section*** **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reviews>
   <ReviewRequest>
     <EEID>1234</EEID>
     <EEFirstName>John</EEFirstName>
     <EEInitial>A</EEInitial>
     <EELastName>Doe</EELastName>
     <EETitle>Title</EETitle>
     <ReviewRequest>2017 Review</ReviewRequest>
     <Goals>
       <Goal>
         <Goal>Goal Title1A</Goal>
         <Score>3</Score>
       </Goal>
       <Goal>
         <Goal>Goal Title1A</Goal>
         <Score>2</Score>
       </Goal>
     </Goals>
  </ReviewRequest>
  <ReviewRequest>
     <EEID>1234</EEID>
     <EEFirstName>John</EEFirstName>
     <EEInitial>A</EEInitial>
     <EELastName>Doe</EELastName>
     <EETitle>Title</EETitle>
     <ReviewRequest>2018 Review</ReviewRequest>
     <Goals>
       <Goal>
         <Goal>Goal Title1B</Goal>
         <Score>2</Score>
       </Goal>
       <Goal>
         <Goal>Goal Title1B</Goal>
         <Score>3</Score>
       </Goal>
     </Goals>
  </ReviewRequest>
</Reviews>
```

I've tried with the following XSL, but I don't seem to be using the right selector or getting the grouping right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:fct="http://www.taleo.com/xsl_functions" xmlns:e="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:so="http://www.taleo.com/ws/so750/2006/12" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/ExportXML">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="./record" group-by="field[@name='ReviewRequest']">
            <xsl:variable name="EEID" select="field[@name='EmployeeEmployeeID']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="EEFirstName" select="field[@name='EmployeeFirstName']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="EEInitial" select="field[@name='EmployeeInitial']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="EELastName" select="field[@name='EmployeeLastName']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="EETitle" select="field[@name='EmployeeTitle']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ReviewRequest" select="field[@name='ReviewRequest']"/>

            <ReviewRequest>
                <xsl:element name="EEID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="EEID"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="EEFirstName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="EEFirstName"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="EEInitial">
                    <xsl:value-of select="EEInitial"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="EELastName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="EELastName"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="EETitle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="EETitle"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="ReviewRequest">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ReviewRequest"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Goal">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="" group-by="field[@name='ReviewRequest']">
                        <xsl:element name="Goals">
                            <xsl:element name="Name">
                                <xsl:variable name="Goal" select="field[@name='Goal']"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Goal"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Goals"/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:element>
            </ReviewRequest>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current xsl just outputs the value without tags and no grouping...

```
    1234
    John
    A
    Doe
    Title
    2017 Review
    Goal Title1A


    1234
    John
    A
    Doe
    Title
    2017 Review
    Goal Title2A


    1234
    John
    A
    Doe
    Title
    2018 Review
    Goal Title1B


    1234
    John
    A
    Doe
    Title
    2018 Review
    Goal Title2B
```

I started with the suggestion below and ended up with the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ExportXML">
    <Reviews>    
      <xsl:for-each-group select="record" 
        group-by="string-join((field[@name=('EmployeeEmployeeID','ReviewRequest')]),
        '|')">
        <ReviewRequest>
          <EEID>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeEmployeeID']"/>
          </EEID>
          <EEFirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeFirstName']"/>
          </EEFirstName>
          <EEInitial>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeInitial']"/>
          </EEInitial>
          <EELastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeLastName']"/>
          </EELastName>
          <EETitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeTitle']"/>
          </EETitle>
          <ReviewRequest>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='ReviewRequest']"/>
          </ReviewRequest>
            <Goals>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/field[@name='Goal']">
                    <Goal>
                        <Goal><xsl:value-of select="."/></Goal>
                        <Score><xsl:value-of select="../field[@name='Score']"/></Score>
                    </Goal>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Goals>
        </ReviewRequest>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </Reviews>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Reviews>
   <ReviewRequest>
      <EEID>1234</EEID>
      <EEFirstName>John</EEFirstName>
      <EEInitial>A</EEInitial>
      <EELastName>Doe</EELastName>
      <EETitle>Title</EETitle>
      <ReviewRequest>2017 Review</ReviewRequest>
      <Goals>
         <Goal>
            <Goal>Goal Title1A</Goal>
            <Score>3</Score>
         </Goal>
         <Goal>
            <Goal>Goal Title2A</Goal>
            <Score>2</Score>
         </Goal>
      </Goals>
   </ReviewRequest>
   <ReviewRequest>
      <EEID>1234</EEID>
      <EEFirstName>John</EEFirstName>
      <EEInitial>A</EEInitial>
      <EELastName>Doe</EELastName>
      <EETitle>Title</EETitle>
      <ReviewRequest>2018 Review</ReviewRequest>
      <Goals>
         <Goal>
            <Goal>Goal Title1B</Goal>
            <Score>2</Score>
         </Goal>
         <Goal>
            <Goal>Goal Title2B</Goal>
            <Score>3</Score>
         </Goal>
      </Goals>
   </ReviewRequest>
</Reviews>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8v/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you're getting is the result of the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule). This is because you don't account for the default namespace (`http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07`). So `/ExportXML` doesn't match anything.

In addition to accounting for the default namespace also consider using a composite group-by instead of two nested for-each-group's.

The grouping-key would be a combination of the "EmployeeEmployeeID" field and the "ReviewRequest" field.

Assuming that everything other than the Goals would be the same for each group, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ExportXML">
    <Reviews>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="record" 
        group-by="string-join((field[@name=('EmployeeEmployeeID','ReviewRequest')]),
        '|')">
        <ReviewRequest>
          <EEID>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeEmployeeID']"/>
          </EEID>
          <EEFirstName>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeFirstName']"/>
          </EEFirstName>
          <EEInitial>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeInitial']"/>
          </EEInitial>
          <EELastName>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeLastName']"/>
          </EELastName>
          <EETitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='EmployeeTitle']"/>
          </EETitle>
          <ReviewRequest>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/field[@name='ReviewRequest']"/>
          </ReviewRequest>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/field[@name='Goal']">
            <Goal><xsl:value-of select="."/></Goal>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ReviewRequest>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </Reviews>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5t

You could also simplify the element creation a little (this one also accounts for your added `Score` requirement)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/ExportXML">
    <Reviews>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="record" 
        group-by="string-join((field[@name=('EmployeeEmployeeID','ReviewRequest')]),
        '|')">
        <ReviewRequest>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="current-group()[1]/field[not(@name=('Goal','Score'))]"/>
          <Goals>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/field[@name='Goal']"/>
          </Goals>
        </ReviewRequest>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </Reviews>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field[@name='Goal']">
    <Goal>
      <Goal><xsl:value-of select="."/></Goal>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../field[@name='Score']"/>
    </Goal>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:element name="{replace(@name,'^(Employee)+(.*)','EE$2')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Updated fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5t/2

Comment: Thank you! This is already working much better than what I had before! A couple of things. I actually will have a few extra fields for each Goal, so I need to create a Goals sections with each goal having the Name and the score.

Comment: This is my current progress

Comment: @BenEsteban - I updated my second stylesheet and fiddle to handle your `Score` requirement.

Comment: @BenEsteban - Now that I look at your question closer, I see you're getting the same output I am and it appears to be the output you wanted. Did you really have an additional question?

Comment: At this point the output looks great! Thank you for your help!